How to debug error 401/403 for Google Calendar API?
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

i am being thrown this error after trying to user Google Calendar API's insert function.

import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './home.css';
import {gapi} from 'gapi-script'

function Home() {
  
  const [val, setVal] = useState("schedule a dinner at Denny's from 6pm to 8pm?");
 
  
  const makeGoogleCalendarApiCall = async () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!token) {
      console.error("No OAuth token found, please log in again.");
      return;
    }
  
    gapi.load('client', async () => {
      try {
        await gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3');
        console.log('Google Calendar API loaded successfully');
        console.log('token in gapi client load', token)
        // Set the OAuth token
        gapi.client.setToken({ access_token: token });
  
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error loading Calendar API or making API call:', error);
      }
    });
  };
  

 const click = async () => {
   const apiKey2 = //GPT API KEY
   const apiUrl = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'
   const tok = localStorage.getItem('token')
   console.log('tok: ', tok)
  makeGoogleCalendarApiCall()
  try {
     const result = await fetch(apiUrl, {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey2}`,
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({
         model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
         messages: [
           { role: "system", content: "You are a helpful assistant." },
           { role: "user", content: `Please provide the following event details in JSON format using ${val}: Summary, Location, Start Time, End Time. For example, if the user says 'schedule dinner tomorrow from 6pm to 8pm at home', the output should be structured JSON like this:
             {
               "summary": "Dinner",
               "location": "Home",
               "start": "6pm",
               "end": "8pm"
             }
             Convert the start and end times to RFC3339 format and the year is 2024. If you are not confident in filling out the output, or if user does not provide information, leave it empty. If end time is left empty and start is filled, assume the end time is one hour later. Respond with only the JSON format do not say anything else.` }
         ],
         max_tokens: 100,
         temperature: 0.7,
       }),
     });


     const data = await result.json();
     const reply = data.choices[0].message.content;


     console.log('OpenAI Response:', reply);
     const eventData = JSON.parse(reply); 


     console.log('Extracted Event Data:', eventData);


    


     const event = {
       'summary': eventData.summary,
       'location': eventData.location,
       'start': {
         'dateTime': eventData.start,
         'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
       },
       'end': {
         'dateTime': eventData.end,
         'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
       },
       'recurrence': [
         'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
       ],
       
     };
      
     

     console.log('outside insert')
     console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));  // Ensure a token is present
      gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
        calendarId: 'primary',
        resource: event,
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log('Event created:', response.result.htmlLink);
        window.open(response.result.htmlLink); // Open the event link
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error creating event:', error);
      })
        
      return eventData;

   } catch (error) {
     console.error("Error response:", error);
   }
 };


 const change = event => {
   setVal(event.target.value);
 };


 return (
   <div>
     <input
       onChange={change}
       value={val}
       className="input"
     />
     <button className="button" onClick={click}></button>
   </div>
 );
}


export default Home;

essentially, I am trying to take in user input and plug that into OpenAI API which will be plugged into Calendar API so I can create an event. so for example, if i were to input "schedule me a dinner at Denny's from 6pm to 8pm", this would be turned into a JSON through OpenAI API and then GCal API will take the JSON and insert it as an event. this is one segment of code, i have one or two other files that handles Google login. which makes me wonder if the GIS login has anything to do with this since? also, im relatively new to programming so excuse my code if the structure/method is not the best.
